# Updated Django User model with profile now cant log in new users

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, djoser

I have updated the user model fields with user profile fields and now I can not seem to log in new users. I am using Djoser to handle these actions. A new user can sign up which updates the user object but I keep getting  `non_field_errors: Unable to log in with provided credentials.`

I have tried the following in settings.py to no avail:

```
DJOSER = {
    'LOGIN_FIELD': 'username',
    'SERIALIZERS': {
    'user_create': 'profiles.serializers.UserSerializer',
    'user': 'profiles.serializers.UserSerializer'
    }
}
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'profiles.Profile'
```

Models.py:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    residence = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    active_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    avatar = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to ='uploads/profile_pics',default='uploads/default.jpg')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.avatar.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.avatar.path)
```

Serializers.py:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)
    avatar = serializers.ImageField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile       
        fields = "__all__"

class ProfileAvatarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile       
        fields = ("avatar", )

class ProfileStatusSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user_profile = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ProfileStatus       
        fields = "__all__"

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = ProfileSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('profile', 'username', 'password')

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):

       if 'profile' in validated_data:
            nested_serializer = self.fields['profile']
            nested_instance = instance.profile
            nested_data = validated_data.pop('profile')

            # Runs the update on whatever serializer the nested data belongs to
            nested_serializer.update(nested_instance, nested_data)

        # Runs the original parent update(), since the nested fields were
        # "popped" out of the data
            return super(UserSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: one solution would be to delete you database, and all your current migration files and rerun the migration. this is because changes to the auth system once a database migration has been made can be some times irrevesible and it is advised in the official documentation to customize the use model (if needed) before the first migration is made

Comment: Ok try it know. I havent been able to remigrate the database as I am getting ```AttributeError: type object 'Profile' has no attribute 'USERNAME_FIELD'```

Comment: have you cleared your database